# svg GaussianBlur ломается область видимости

Tags: css3, svg, background

Как правильно задавать параметры для фильтра, чтобы не обрезалось по квадрату.
 Не могу понять, где эта область видимости задается?

```css
.decor_background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, #111 2%, #221c44);
  filter: blur(20px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.svg_elements {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.svg_circle {
  width: 50px;
}

#svg_elements__full {
  width: 100%;
}

.svg_circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #68CADA;
  stroke-width: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="decor_background"></div>

<div class="svg_elements">
  <svg version="1.1" id="svg_elements__full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
        <filter id="i1" width="150%">
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="10"/>
        </filter>
        <symbol id="myCircle">
            <circle class="svg_circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="24"/>
            <circle class="svg_circle" filter="url(#i1)" cx="50" cy="50" r="28"/>
        </symbol>
        <use xlink:href="#myCircle" transform="translate(10,85)"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Область видимости действия фильтра на объект называется - [Filter effects region](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion)

Это прямоугольник, с габаритными размерами `width="X%"`, `height="Y%"` заданными в определении фильтра   `<filter id="i1" width="150%">`

Также могут быть заданы координаты левого верхнего угла `региона действия фильтра` - `x="X%"` `y="Y%"`

Если эти все параметры не указаны, то они будут по умолчанию равны:

`x="-10%"`, `y="-10%"` `width="120%"` `height="120%"`

Вы  указали в своем примере только `width="150%"` без `height`

В результате регион действия фильтра уменьшился и подрезал края.

Внизу пример с новыми параметрами региона фильтра:

```css
.decor_background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, #111 2%, #221c44);
  filter: blur(20px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.svg_elements {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.svg_circle {
  width: 50px;
}

#svg_elements__full {
  width: 100%;
}

.svg_circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #68CADA;
  stroke-width: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="decor_background"></div>

<div class="svg_elements">
  <svg version="1.1" id="svg_elements__full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 800 800" >
        <filter id="i1" y="-15%" x="-15%" height="130% "width="130%">
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut"  stdDeviation="4"/>
        </filter>
        <symbol id="myCircle">
             <circle class="svg_circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="24" /> 
            <circle class="svg_circle" filter="url(#i1)" cx="50" cy="50" r="28"/> 
        </symbol>
        <use xlink:href="#myCircle" transform="translate(10,85)"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**Update**

*Ваш пример  работает только `Chrome`, `Opera`, `Yandex`, но не работает в `Firefox`*

Необходимо убрать параметр `in="offOut"` из определения фильтра и тогда будет работать и в `Firefox`

```css
.decor_background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, #111 2%, #221c44);
  filter: blur(20px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.svg_elements {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.svg_circle {
  width: 50px;
}

#svg_elements__full {
  width: 100%;
}

.svg_circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #68CADA;
  stroke-width: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="decor_background"></div>

<div class="svg_elements">
  <svg version="1.1" id="svg_elements__full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 800 800" >
        <filter id="i1" y="-9%" x="-15%" height="200% "width="200%">
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut"  stdDeviation="3.5"/>
        </filter>
        <symbol id="myCircle">
             <circle class="svg_circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="24" /> 
            <circle class="svg_circle" filter="url(#i1)" cx="50" cy="50" r="28"/> 
        </symbol>
        <use xlink:href="#myCircle" transform="translate(10,85)" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо за столь развернутый ответ